# CKEditor: use both classic and inline editing mode

Tags: ckeditor

I want the users the have the possibility to choose between classic editing mode and inline editing mode of the content. Is this possible, or you can only use one mode?

Comment: Since CKEditor 4.2 you can also turn <textarea> elements into inline editors. When you call the CKEDITOR.inline method on a <textarea>, an additional <div> element with inline editing enabled will replace the original <textarea>.

Comment: This does not answer my question to whether I can have BOTH methods active and have the end user CHOOSE which to use between the two... or at least not in a way I can understand :/